# FB Comments fed code

Tags: facebook, comments

Is there another link to the page "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments"
This page doesn't work and comes up with a 500 error. 
I am looking to be the moderator to edit posts and approve them. Is this broken page where I need to go for this?

Comment: For how long do you have this issue ? I can access it without problems.

Comment: Since yesterday morning

Comment: Are you a Devp of Facebook or something special that allows you to see that page?

Answer (score 0):

The page was showing up as blank for me as well. I had to have administrator role in the facebook app, not just developer.